# Treating a folder like an array

Tags: vb.net, directory

Is it possible to treat a folder like an array? So that the first file in it is treated as File 0, the second File 1 etc?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but you would need to know how big the array is from the onset.  I am not really sure why you would want to do this but, a `List<>` may be more suited to your needs.

Comment: Well I know how many files are in the folder, and I want to cycle through them. There's a lot of them though and they could change, so I'd like to find the file name just by a numerical reference.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense.  As has been mentioned below, I would use the `Directory.GetAllFiles()` method since the files can change.  The problem with using an array for what you want is that you have to define the size of the array when you initialize it. They aren't really all that flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you mean this:

```
Dim allFiles() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("folder path")
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great, but for some reason when it hits the 999th file it stops, any ideas why? Is that just the array character limit?

Comment: @niallmcfc It should deal with as many files as required. This array has no dimension and thus is resized accordingly to the retrieved records. 999 sounds pretty low to be the upper limit GetFiles(), but never tested with so many files..

Comment: @niallmcfc have tested it and works fine with over 1000 files. Why are you saying that?

Comment: @niallmcfc Ah OK (do I know you?)... you can dimension arrays as big as you wish but it is recommendable to not make too big sizes (there might memory isssues... but with big programs, not with a small application). I do actually recommend to not dimension arrays over 1000 as a general rule. But this array has not dimension, grows as big as the number of files. If you are having a small application (on a modern computer) you don't need to worry about array sizes too much; but it is convenient to have present that the size might matter and that relying on many/big arrays is not a good thing.

Comment: As far as I know I don't know you...

Anyway, on topic, the folder path may be too long. I'm just testing it now

Comment: @niallmcfc OK (just found curious the 999 thing). Yes. There is a problem with too long paths with System.IO (also while using Windows); but it should be fine in most of the cases.

Comment: It's weird, I tried it with a shorter path and it still stopped- this is the code snippet: http://pastebin.com/7s89XvCW

Comment: @niallmcfc can you please share the given path? There has to be a problem with file; the number (999) shouldn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, this would be an example: "C:\Users\Niall\Desktop\MT Provs\999filename.txt". I was trying it earlier with a much longer name and it still stopped at 999.

Comment: @niallmcfc the path seems fine; the code seems fine. Might it be an ordering issue? Perhaps you are expecting more than 999filename.txt but actually this is the last file (because of the way the folder is sorted... all the other files have already been accounted for in previous positions of the array). To make sure, check the length of the array to confirm the number of elements it contains.

Comment: Ah, that's bizarre. If I put in "Console.WriteLine(provFiles.Length)", it gives the array length as being correct (2795). So I guess the problem lies with the console not outputting every file name?

Comment: @niallmcfc ah!... what I said, this is an ordering issue. I guess that you have 1filename.txt, 2filename.txt, 3filename.txt, etc. and you look at the last position and expect to see 2795filename.txt, but this does not have to be the case. All the files are in the array, but not necessarily in the order to want. you might have to sort the array to get what you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all your help :) I'd love to upvote this a load of times, but I'm 1 rep point off ;_; Thanks anyway for your help and time!

Comment: @niallmcfc You can vote up now ;). (With that power, you can totally vote up both this answer and mine, since we both answered the same answer at the same time. :p)

Comment: Haha, thanks a lot, have done. Will have to go back now upvoting the people that helped me in the past :P

Comment: @neminem I know (same minute and same second), that's I upvoted you. In any case, you shouldn't upvote just to unlock privileges, but well... :)

Answer (score 2):

Try [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx). Calling that with a folder path as input, returns an output of an array of file paths of all the files in the folder.